# How to clear/ reset a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, validation, repaint, removeall

Me and my friend have decided to work on a card game which cycles between 3 screens (**Player1HandScreen, Player2HandScreen and FightScreen**).

Once Player1 has chosen their card from `Player1HandScreen`, `Player1HandScreen` leads to `Player2HandScreen` where Player2 does the same. then `Player2HandScreen` leads to `FightScreen` where the two cards are compared and one player is declared the winner of that round.

The problem we are having is that once the round ends we want to clear `Player1HandScreen` as well as the `Player2HandScreen` once refreshing our parameters we are having trouble updating the GUI successfully.

We have have tried to use `removeAll()`, but we can't get it to `repaint()` or `validate()`.

We have also looked into `super.paintComponents(g)` and `updateUI()` but both have left us with crushed hopes and dreams.

Answer (score 5):

if you remove any JComponent(s) from Container (only once on the end), is needed tell to Container for,

```
removeAll()//or remove(JComponent)
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: I am still getting an empty screen. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @breadedchicken really time to edit and post short code (one two JComponets) that demostrated your issue, anythig other are shots to the dark

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear you Jpanel using:

```
paper.clearRect(0, 0, (int)panel.getSize().getWidth(), (int)panel.getSize().getHeight
```

where paper is something like: `Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();`