# Closing Java Frame

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a java game and have implemented a GameOver method. This is the code i have for the game over method:

```
public void gameOver() throws IOException {
   String message = "Game, Want to try Again?";
   String title = "Game Over";
   int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        new Game();
    } else {
        this.getSoundEffect().stopAllMusic();
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

An issue i am having is closing the original frame. For e.g. if i click yes the Game frame will open, however, it is already open so i would have two instances of the game working.

Just to let you guys know, i have tried the following options:

```
    frame.dispose();

    WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I was also thinking of doing an actionperformed event, however, i was unable due to the JOptionPane being an int.

Comment: might want to check this out...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260855/how-to-clear-reset-a-jframe

Comment: have you kept a reference to The `Game` object which is already opened?

Comment: @Aubin, that will close the whole system therefore not allowing me to open another Java class.

Comment: You should have..That will help you to check if the Game window is opened or not..and if opened the dont do anything else create new one.

Comment: @VishalK How would i do that?

Comment: What is Main Class? what it extends?

Comment: The main class is Main.java and it extends JFrame.                public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame

Comment: @JamesDanny Your Main will always be visible in background?

Comment: its my Game.Java that is staying visible not my Main.

Comment: You could try reusing the old frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gameOver` method should be like this:

```
Main mMain ;
public void gameOver() throws IOException {
   String message = "Game, Want to try Again?";
   String title = "Game Over";
   int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        frame.dispose();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        this.getSoundEffect().stopAllMusic();
        if(mMain==null)
        {
          mMain = new Main();
        }
        mMain.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Aside all thse , You have two variables named `frame` first one is instance variable which is `frame = new JFrame("Game");` and other is `final JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Birds Game");` you should change the variable name of other `JFrame`..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work. The game freezes and the game re opens.

Comment: @JamesDanny See my update. One thing more I want to ask you is , If your game frame is opened.. then you want to hide the `Main` frame?

Comment: The main frame is already disposed of. On my main frame it gives me the option to launch my Game.Java when i launch it the Main Frame becomes disposed off.

Comment: The main issue is, that the frame is not being disposed. I am not sure why. I think it is disposing a different frame not the Game.Java frame.

Comment: You mean all contents of the frame are not reset after dispose is called?

Comment: Yes exactly, in your code you putframe.dispose(); frame.setVisible(true); a new empty frame window opened up.

Comment: ahh ..then you should not call dispose..call `frame.setVisible(false)` instead.

Comment: The main thing that is missing in your code is that...You have not provided the option for `reset` the `frame`. i.e. When game finished and user wants to restarts..then frame reset to its initial configuration.. You should work upon that...

Comment: Oh ok, ill have a go at that. Any advice of how to do it would be appreciated!

Comment: You have two variables named `frame` first one is instance variable which is `frame = new JFrame("Game");` and other is `final JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Birds Game - By Moe Tarhini");` in same constructor. why?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you that was the issue! Thank you so so much! i stupidly but two variables named frame! finally lol